# How to use md5.js within a compontent?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I just started working with Ember-CLI 0.0.36 and I'm stuck with the Gravatar example code from the [Ember.js homepage](http://emberjs.com/).

I did

```
> bower install --save JavaScript-MD5
> ember generate component gravatar-image
```

**Brocfile.js**

```
[...]
app.import('vendor/JavaScript-MD5/js/md5.js');
[...]
```

**app/components/gravatar-image.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  size: 200,
  email: '',

  gravatarUrl: function() {
    var email = this.get('email'),
        size = this.get('size');

    return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + md5(email) + '?s=' + size;
  }.property('email', 'size')
});
```

After starting `ember server` I'll get the following error message:

```
xyz/components/gravatar-image.js: line 11, col 48, 'md5' is not defined.
1 error
```

How can I tell the component to use JavaScript-MD5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript-MD5 does't export any AMD-Modules, if I see it right. But it defines `window.md5`. So your `app.import` will include it in `vendor.js` and you can call `window.md5` in the component.

Answer (score 4):

To get this to work I used:

```
bower install blueimp-md5 --save-dev
```

and added import in Brocfile.js

```
app.import('bower_components/blueimp-md5/js/md5.js');
```

then add "md5" to predef array as mentioned by Oliver to suppress md5 warning.

Answer (score 3):

That's just a jshint linter message.

Open your .jshintrc file, add `"md5"` to the `"predef"` object and you are fine.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to install the `ember-cli-md5` package. This will install all the required dependencies in your node modules.
Use this `npm install --save-dev ember-cli-md5` to install `ember-cli-md5`.

Once installed you will need to generate md-5 which will install the browser package via bower.
Use this to generate md-5 `ember generate md-5`.

So, you need to perform following two steps:-

```
npm install --save-dev ember-cli-md5
ember generate md-5
```